# Can i get insert id when using laravel model create method Model::create

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using this code:

```
\App\Models\City::create(['name' => 'Los Angeles' , 'state' => 'CA']);
```

how to get its id?

Comment: just assign it to a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can assign creation of an object to a variable, and then use it's properties:

```
$city = \App\Models\City::create([
   'name' => 'Los Angeles',
   'state' => 'CA'
]);

dd($city->id) //Get the id of a city
```